# How to bind to user controls using ReactiveUI and winforms

Tags: winforms, binding, system.reactive, reactiveui

I am trying to learn ReactiveUI. I have been looking at the wpf sample project in the repository https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/tree/master/samples/getting-started

I decided to try to convert this to winforms but have a problem.

In the wpf example the search function populates, via OAPH, a property of the 'Main' ViewModel (AppViewModel) called SearchResults which is an IEnumerable of 'Child' ViewModels (NuGetDetailsViewModel)

```
public IEnumerable<NugetDetailsViewModel> SearchResults => _searchResults.Value;
```

in the 'Main' View (MainWindow) there is a listbox which has its ItemSource bound to the SearchResults i.e. the IEnumerable of ViewModels.
There seems to be some wizardry going on that finds and displays the appropriate View for the given ViewModel. It even says so in the comments:

> In our MainWindow when we register the ListBox with the collection of NugetDetailsViewModels if no ItemTemplate has been declared it will search for a class derived off IViewFor and show that for the item.

---

In winforms I *think* I have two problems, but I maybe out by one.. or more:

1. It doesnt seem like the same wizardry of finding the View for the ViewModel is working, however this may be due to problem two.
2. How can I bind the IEnumerable of ViewModels to a winforms control?

---

In winforms I am using a flowlayoutpanel in place of the ListBox and have tried several variations of:

```
this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.ResultsList, v => v.flowLayoutPanel1.DataBindings)
```

I have been able to use some conversion code directly in the View to update the flowLayoutPanel directly but it requires direct knowledge of the Child View and doesn't sit well with me, and isn't as automatic as I would like.

```
this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, 
            vm => vm.ResultsList,
            v  => v.flowLayoutPanel1, 
            selector: value => 
            {
                this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
                foreach (var value in values)
                {
                    this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new AssemblyInfoView() { ViewModel = value });
                }
                return this.flowLayoutPanel1;
            } ));
```

---

For clarity the 'Child' View linked to my 'Child' ViewModel also derives from ReactiveUserControl.

I use the following code to register the Views:

```
Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterViewsForViewModels(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
```

and have checked that they are registered.

---

If anyone is able to help that would be appreciated.

As an addendum if anyone knows of some more complex sample projects using ReactiveUI particularly using winforms that would be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: I am adding a demo and some utilities to the ReactiveUI.Winforms library sometime soon.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In [ReactiveUI 9.11](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/releases/tag/9.11.1) there is a new feature which allows you to bind to either any control that has `Control.ControlCollection` or to a `TableLayoutControlCollection`

This will allow you to have it automatically add to the Control's.

This is made available by a new interface called `ISetMethodBindingConverter` which allows you to override how the 'Set' in our binding engine works.

There is now a sample for the WinForms application found here: https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Samples/tree/master/winforms/ReactiveDemo

Comment: Glenn you are a star! That example is excellent. I do have some follow up questions: ISetMethodBindingConverter, is it something that I am going to need to understand? Getting the View from the ViewModel, in general should I pass the ViewModel to the ViewModelControlHost or should I use the ViewLocator, does the ViewModelControlHost do something that im missing? Thank you

Comment: The ViewModelControlHost, has a property called "ViewModel", when this is set it'll search for Control inheriting IViewFor<TViewModel> -- and then will make this the child. If you notice in Program.cs I register the Views, and NugetDetailsView derives off that interface.

Comment: this link is dead.

Comment: @GlennWatson Please fix the sample link, thank you